# C# Bandwidth throttling using custom bindings?

Tags: c#, web-services, .net-4.0

I’m using a service reference  to communicate between my clients (C#) and my server.
I Frequently want to transfer big amounts of data (> 2 MB) over this web service, this works perfectly but with a few customers who has a very small upload this process is very slow and complete fills the upload for a limited time.

I’m looking for a way to limits the bandwidth used by the client to make sure there is some upload available for the customer itself.

I found various solutions the throttle streams but is it possible to use throttle in a web service call?
Maybe using a custom binding?

Comment: Is this really in the scope of your application though? If I understand correctly, your customer has a bandwidth cap that cripples their connection when they upload a file? If so, it's solely their responsibility to perform QoS.

Comment: You’re right, but if I can help him by applying a bandwidth limiter on my application.
Then I have a very happy customer.

Comment: And potentially a bunch of other very frustrated customers, you have no way to know why is the transfer so slow, is it a busy day at the office? is there an issue on your end? who do you limit and why? how do you know who not to limit. It's a can of worms that you don't want to open.